# Javascript mouseover only working on first element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to have an icon change color everytime an input box is hovered. The problem is it is only changing the background when hovering the first input textbox, not the other two.

I'm trying to get this effect without jquery.Thanks in advance for your help !

```js
var input = document.querySelector ('input');
var icon = document.querySelector ('img');

input.addEventListener ('mouseover', function hover(){
  icon.style.background = '#D46855';
});
input.addEventListener ('mouseleave', function leave(){
  icon.style.background = '#81D455';
  
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower');


body{
 background-image :url(https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/max_1200/b0e53331516629.565449774c2d4.png); 
}
h1{
 font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
  font-size:3em;
  color:#D46855;
  letter-spacing:5px;
}

#container{
  text-align:center;
  margin:10% auto;
  padding-top: 50px;
  border-radius:15%;
  width:80%;
  height:400px;
  position:relative;
  background-color : rgba(84, 193, 212, 0.56);
 box-shadow: 5px 5px 4px 5px rgba(84, 193, 212, 0.56);
}

img{
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
  height:100px;
  width : 100px;
  position:absolute;
  top: -95%;
  border-radius:30px;
  background:#81D455;
}

input{
  width:200px;
  height:15px;
  font-size:1.2em;
  padding:10px;
  text-align:center;
  display:flex;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-top:20px;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'container'>
  <h1>To Do List</h1>
  <img src = "https://www.jamiesale-cartoonist.com/wp-content/uploads/cartoon-business-man-free1.png">
  <form>
    
    <input type = 'text' placeholder = 'item' id = 'list' </input>
    <input type = 'text' placeholder = 'item' id = 'list' </input>
    <input type = 'text' placeholder = 'item' id = 'list' </input>
  </form>
   </div>
</body>
```

Any advice would be appreciated (:

Comment: `document.querySelector` returns one single element, the first that matches the supplied selector - you need `document.querySelectorAll` **and iterate through the result**  (disregard CSS solution)

Comment: Well you only put an event listener on 1 of the inputs, you need to put the event on all of them, or use event delegation

Answer (score 9):

`querySelector` returns only the first element that is found.

As you have multiple `input` elements use `querySelectorAll`

```
var input = document.querySelectorAll('input');
```

Also as `querySelectorAll` returns multiple elements ( which is a node list of inputs in this case ) , you will have to attach the event handlers in a loop.

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
var icon = document.querySelector('img');

inputs.forEach(function(input) {
  input.addEventListener('mouseover', function hover() {
    icon.style.background = '#D46855';
  });

  input.addEventListener('mouseleave', function leave() {
    icon.style.background = '#81D455';

  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Sushanth for the help ! Much appreciated (: